# How to detect collision on certain sides of a rectangle in canvas using socket.io

Tags: node.js, html, socket.io, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I am learning multiplayer development and I was wondering how I would detect collision and not allow the player to move into the collision but allow them to move away from it. I currently have a collision detection setup that is server side when the player tries to move. Though this collision detection works perfectly when the players collide they can not move out of the collision and are stuck forever. Here is the code that i'm using server-side to detect when a player moves & or collides:

```
socket.on('moveEvent', function(data) {
  var player = players[find(connections, this.id)]
  var r1 = {
    left: player.position.x,
    top: player.position.y,
    bottom: player.position.y + 100,
    right: player.position.x + 100
  }
  var intersects = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    if (connections[i] != this.id) {
      var currPlayer = players[i]
      var r2 = {
        left: currPlayer.position.x,
        top: currPlayer.position.y,
        bottom: currPlayer.position.y + 100,
        right: currPlayer.position.x + 100
      }
      intersects = intersectRect(r1, r2)
    }
  }
  console.log(intersects)
  if (data.direction == "x+" && intersects == false) {
    player.position.x = player.position.x - speed
  }
  if (data.direction == "y+" && intersects == false) {
    player.position.y = player.position.y - speed
  }
  if (data.direction == "x-" && intersects == false) {
    player.position.x = player.position.x + speed
  }
  if (data.direction == "y-" && intersects == false) {
    player.position.y = player.position.y + speed
  }
});

function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  socket.emit('checkPlayers', {
    p1: r1,
    p2: r2
  })
  if (!(r2.left > r1.right || r2.right < r1.left || r2.top > r1.bottom || r2.bottom < r1.top)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is the setInterval code that gets the new coordinates and draws them to the screen. I currently have an emit event in the intersectRect function that emits the two players it is checking the collision of. The server then takes that emit and prints out the two players it sends. This is strictly for bug fixing:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (w == true) {
    socket.emit('moveEvent', {
      direction: "y+",
      id: sesID
    })
  }
  if (a == true) {
    socket.emit('moveEvent', {
      direction: "x+",
      id: sesID
    })
  }
  if (s == true) {
    socket.emit('moveEvent', {
      direction: "y-",
      id: sesID
    })
  }
  if (d == true) {
    socket.emit('moveEvent', {
      direction: "x-",
      id: sesID
    })
  }
  gamectx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  gamectx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  gamectx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
  socket.emit('request', {
    request: "players",
    id: sesID
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    gamectx.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
    gamectx.fillRect(((game.width / 2) + (players[i].position.x - player.position.x)) - 50, ((game.height / 2) + (players[i].position.y - player.position.y)) - 50, 100, 100)
  }
  gamectx.fillStyle = "#0000ff"
  gamectx.fillRect((window.innerWidth / 2) - 50, (window.innerHeight / 2) - 50, 100, 100);
  gamectx.font = "48px sans-serif";
  gamectx.strokeText("x: " + GameX + ", y: " + GameY, 10, 50);
  var playersList = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    playersList += "x: " + players[i].position.x + ", y: " + players[i].position.y + ", "
  }
  gamectx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  gamectx.strokeText(playersList, 10, 100);
  console.log(p1, p2)
}, 30);
```

So I think I may need to detect collisions on every side and not allow the player to moved in that direction when they collide OR move the player away from the collision when it happens. Thanks for your help in advance. Got no answers so I reposted this hoping for some. Thanks!